# Is there any restrictions on dataset structure if I want to use pooled OLS but control for year dummies?

Tags: least-squares, panel-data

```
   year of |
observatio |      year of observation relative to conversion date (conversion occurs in year 0)
         n |        -4         -3         -2         -1          0          1          2          3 |     Total
-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
      2002 |         9          0          0          0          0          0          0          0 |         9 
      2003 |        16          9          0          0          0          0          0          0 |        25 
      2004 |        28         16          9          0          0          0          0          0 |        53 
      2005 |        44         28         16          9          0          0          0          0 |        97 
      2006 |        61         44         28         16          9          0          0          0 |       158 
      2007 |         0         61         44         28         16          9          0          0 |       158 
      2008 |         0          0         61         44         28         16          9          0 |       158 
      2009 |         0          0          0         61         44         28         16          9 |       158 
      2010 |         0          0          0          0         61         44         28         16 |       149 
      2011 |         0          0          0          0          0         61         44         28 |       133 
      2012 |         0          0          0          0          0          0         61         44 |       105 
      2013 |         0          0          0          0          0          0          0         61 |        61 
-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |       158        158        158        158        158        158        158        158 |     1,264
```

If I want to assess an impact of a certain event (conversion), can I use pooled OLS model but control for year dummies? (year of observation)